# jQuery cycle and fade random records from table

Tags: jquery

I am trying to cycle and fade in/out random records from a table into my webpage.

Here is my code:

**SQL:**

```
SELECT businessid, bsalias, bsname, bswebsite, bsarea, bsstrapline
FROM businesses WHERE businessid >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(businessid) * RAND())
FROM businesses) ORDER BY businessid LIMIT 1
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="divRHSlinksml">
  <h1 class="bss">
    <a href="http://www.letsgowild.co.uk/business/<?php echo $row_rsBusiness['bsalias']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rsBusiness['bsname']; ?></a>
  </h1>
  <p class="nomarginbase bss">
    <?php if ($row_rsBusiness['bsstrapline'] != ""){
      echo $row_rsBusiness['bsstrapline'];
    } else {
      echo $row_rsBusiness['bsarea'];
    } ?>
  </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery (at end of page):**

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Slideshow
  jQuery('.bss').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    speed: 1000,
    random: 1
  });
</script>
```

At the moment a random record is brought in but it doesn't fade in/out to another record.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your PHP only returns one record. I'm not familiar with the `.cycle()` plugin, but I would guess that your PHP should return all of the records and then `.cycle()` would cycle through them.

Comment: Thanks yes that's helped, plus keeping all cycled content in one 'child' element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL now limit to only 1 record, change it to:

```
SELECT businessid, bsalias, bsname, bswebsite, bsarea, bsstrapline
FROM businesses WHERE businessid >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(businessid) * RAND())
FROM businesses) ORDER BY businessid
```

I don't see your main PHP code but you should loop through the result from SQL query. The JS code can remain the same.

Comment: Thanks, edited the SQL to pull 40 random records in, then looped through the results as your suggestion. jQuery cycle cycles each child element in (.bss) div so I have grouped them and used a span tag to resize elements.

Comment: I am guessing pulling 40 records in is quicker than all of them or does it not make any difference?

Comment: The SQL execution time will be nearly the same (if all are around 100 or something), but rendering will be faster with less record